# Unable to read Excel file in R-studio

Tags: r, import-from-excel

```
install.packages('read_excel')  
library(xlsx)  
read.xlsx(path, sheet = "C:/Users/Vikas Singh/Desktop/Data KNN.xlsx",sheet=2 , range = NULL, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 0, n_max = Inf)
```

Even after using the above code I'm getting an error message no function read.xlsx

Comment: I think you mean `install.packages("xlsx")`. There is no package called read_excel. That is a function from the readxl package.

Answer (score 1):

The `read.xlsx` is a function from the `openxlsx` package.
You need install and load the `readxl` package.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library(readxl)
```

Then try the following code:

```
read_excel(path = "C:/Users/Vikas Singh/Desktop/Data KNN.xlsx", sheet = 2, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `openxlsx` package. Please read the according documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.1.0.1/topics/read.xlsx). Try out the following code:

```
install.packages("openxlsx")
library(openxlsx)  

read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "C:/Users/Vikas Singh/Desktop/DataKNN.xlsx", sheet= <sheet_index> , <... all_your_other_arguments>)
```